# Building a simple DIY rc car, am I missing anything?

Tags: pi-3, remote, connection

I'm planning to do a simple DIY car that is controlled with a smartphone.
I'm new to DIY electronics, and would like to get all of the needed electronic components with a single order.
Could you check out this list and tell me if i'm missing anything essential?

- RPi3B
- 2x DC motors
- Motor controller
- Power supply or batteries
- Non-electronic stuff (4x wheels, chassis etc.)
- Wires (What type of wire should I buy?)

As i have understood the RPi3B comes with onboard WiFi and bluetooth and has the ability to setup a hotspot, so all I need is a smartphone and programming skills for a wireless connection (?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Does your motor driver support controlling 2 motors?
- Have you thought about talking to your motor driver(from the Pi)?

  - keep in mind the Bluetooth does use up the Pi's UART! (see comments for more information)
- For quick wiring, [those](https://www.conrad.de/de/raspberry-pi-verbindungskabel-rb-cb1-25-1192229.html) are great, either many of them, or in bulk like the one I just found(you could also tear them apart when needed)
- For solid constructions, you should consider soldering classic copper wires as well as getting [connectors](http://www.modmypi.com/raspberry-pi/gpio-and-breadboarding/40-pin-gpio-connectors/40-pin-gpio-connector-header-extender), to not have to solder to your components directly
- Yes, the Pi3 has WiFi and BT, but you only need 1 of them for your remote control, unless the Pi itself is supposed to be controlling the car remotely

  - e.g. Smartphone -> Wifi -> Pi -> Bluetooth -> RC car

Regarding programming, you would need to write both sides on your own, a smartphone app, utilizing either BT or WiFi and the Pi's response, which will be talking to your motor driver.

Comment: Um, are you sure "the Bluetooth does use up the Pi's UART" on the Pi 3?  It's my understanding that the bluetooth node uses `ttyAMA0`, but that is **not** the UART on the breakout -- it uses a *different node* than previous models, `ttyS0`.  They should both be usable at the same time.

Comment: Yes, I am. ttyS0 is just the mini UART, which is not reliable as it is based on the cpu clock.

Comment: Ah.  Well at least there appears to be a way to swap one for the other at boot time [see the end, about device tree, here](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/45571/5538).  Otherwise I will be mailing mine straight back when it get here, lol.

Comment: That is indeed possible but I would not recommend it for neither the motor controller nor bluetooth since communication failures won't be fun there.
The only workaround would be to set the CPU frequency to a fixed value. Other than that, the mini UART does not lack crucial features his fully fledged brother provides in such applications. [See page 10](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/2885/BCM2835Datasheet.pdf)

Comment: @mystery The UART is only unreliable if the core clock frequency changes.  You can set a fixed core clock frequency and take a small performance hit (the performance hit wouldn't even kick in for this sort of application).

Comment: Would be interesting to see this work with NodeJS running on the PI :P

Answer (score 1):

Every thing is fine just for a simple car. If you want you can add some LED's .
And in case of wires use
[Jumper Wires](http://www.amazon.in/Jumper-Wire-20-Male-Female/dp/B0117K9PG6/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1467122146&sr=8-1&keywords=jumper%20wires)